# How to extract key value pair from a Url

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I just started developing an application that requires a social website account, so I created a webView for parsing it. 
 In objective c I can get "user_id" parameter by writing this code :

```
NSArray *userAr = [[[[webView request] URL] absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&user_id="];
NSString *user_id = [userAr lastObject];
```

**My question is : how can I write this in c#? Which function can do the same as componentsSeparatedByString?**

Comment: Please give your questions meaningful titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String.Split()

```
string[] array = inputString.Split(new [] {"&user_id="}, StringSplitOptions.None);
string id = array[1];
```

However, this is a brittle solution and will only work if "&user_id=" is the last key value pair in the url.

Comment: Hamarin Studio shows me an error : the best match for "string.Split(params char[])" has some invalid arguments